# Different behavior in bash string comparison while inside a function

Tags: bash, function, awk, directory, string-comparison

There's the following part in a shell script I'm writing:

(Find the latest directory in `someDir` which is not `summary/`)

```
latestDirName=""
for dirName in `ls -lt /user/someDir/ | head -3 | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $9}'`
  do
    if [ "$dirName" == "summary" ]; then
      continue
    fi
    latestDirName=$dirName
  done
```

Here `$dirname` is compared against string `summary`, while an echo of `dirName` variable during the iteration will print as `summary/`

This comparison part works all fine when the code is written in a file and executed.

But once this same code is put inside a function and placed in my bashrc, the comparison in `if` check doesn't seem to work!

Does this have anything to do with the string being a directory name, or it having the `/`?
What difference does it make when the same code is inside a function?

Code inside bashrc:

```
findLatestDir()
{
  latestDirName=""
  for dirName in `ls -lt /user/someDir/ | head -3 | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $9}'`
    do
      if [ "$dirName" == "summary" ]; then
        continue
      fi
      latestDirName=$dirName
    done
}
```

The scripts are called as follows:
Case #1 (code in file): `$ ./findLatestDir.sh`
Case #2 (function in bashrc): `$ findLatestDir`

Comment: The `continue` makes no sense for me

Comment: Please post code that demonstrates how you create and call the function, and that demonstrates the incorrect behavior you are observing.

Comment: hek2mgl Why?
chepner Updated the question with complete details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have an alias or function definition for `ls` in your .bashrc, which interacts poorly with your use of `ls` in the function? If so, explicitly saying `/bin/ls` in the function may solve the problem.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it directly addresses the question at hand

Answer (score 1):

[Parsing `ls` is never a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `stat` instead: print out the epoch modification time, sort numerically in descending order, then find the first dir that is not "summary".

```
findLatestDir() (
    cd /some/dir
    stat -c $'%Y\t%n' */ | 
    sort -rn | 
    cut -f2 | { 
        while read dir; do 
            [[ $dir == "summary/" ]] || break
        done
        echo $dir
    }
)
```

Note that the bash wildcard `*/` with the trailing directory limits the results to directories only.

I execute the function in a subshell so the `cd` command does not affect your current directory.